# Не получается сделать проверку в юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d, mono

Пробую сделать проверку ли скрыт объект или нет

И вылазит такая ошибка:

Assets\Scripts\StartMenuChecker.cs(11,12): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'bool'

Код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class StartMenuChecker : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject startmenu;

    public void Check()
    {
        if(startmenu.SetActive(true))
        {
            startmenu.SetActive(false);
        }
        if (startmenu.SetActive(false))
        {
            startmenu.SetActive(true);
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: `.SetActive()` - это простой `void` метод, который ничего не возвращает. С чего вы взяли, что это `bool`? Смотрите хотяб подсказки IDE, которую используете, уж не говорю про документацию. Хотите `bool` - `.activeSelf` свойство в помощь. А вообще, я надеюсь вы понимаете, что делаете ерунду? Ваша цель какая? Если переключить статус, ок, как инвертировать `bool`? Да просто: `!true` (воскл знак). Имея это, **весь** ваш код можно написать простым `startmenu.SetActive(!startmenu.activeSelf);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй использовать это

```
public GameObject startmenu;
bool Check;

public void StartMenuCheck() {
    Check = !Check;
    startmenu.SetActive(Check);
}
```

или еще проще

```
public GameObject startmenu;

public void Check() {
startmenu.SetActive(!startmenu.activeSelf);
}
```

Comment: Еще больше ошибок появилось

Comment: каких? Напиши, подскажу

Comment: Ане все норм я не так просто сделал

Comment: ладно, тогда удачи

Comment: и пометь пожалуйста мой ответ как правильный)

Comment: О, только заметил, у вас поле и метод одинаково называются, этот код не скомпилируется. И стоило бы добавить небольшое пояснение к проблеме автора, это может пригодиться будущим посетителям.

Comment: простите, делал на скорую руку)